# How to change the padding of TableItems in Eclipse RAP

Tags: eclipse-rap

I have next situation, look at the picture, please. [image]

How can I change this padding value? I need reduce it.

Comment: This is Eclipse RAP, I can't give you a fiddle

Comment: You probably want to include [tag:eclipse-rap] in the question tags to make it more likely that someone who knows about RAP sees the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RWT Theming Reference](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/3.0/guide/reference/theming/index.html) lists a `Table-Cell` CSS rule that has a `padding` property, that

> Defines the padding (i.e. the inner distance between border and content) for a table cell.

Without having tried, you should be able to specify a custom padding with

```
Table-Cell {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

See also the [RWT Theming](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=theming.html&version=3.0) chapter of the developer's guide for more.

Comment: Thanks, you often help me out =)))